# C++ Thread Safe Lazy Load

Tags: c++, multithreading, lazy-loading

I have a property which is similar to the following:

```
private:
Foo* myFoo_m;

public:
Foo getMyFoo() const
{
    if (myFoo_m == NULL)
    {
       myFoo_m = new Foo();
       // perform initialization
```

This works well in a single-threaded environment, but **how do I handle this in a multi-threaded environment?** Most of the info I've found deals with static singletons, but in this case, myFoo is a public instance property.

I am porting this over from C# (where I can use Lazy) and Java (where I can use double check locking), but it doesn't seem that there is a straightforward way to do this in C++. **I cannot rely on any external libraries (no BOOST), and this needs to work on windows and linux.** I also cannot use C++11.

Any insight would be good. I am new to C++.

Comment: does the compiler support c++11 ?

Comment: no, unfortunately it does not.

Comment: for sure, do read 'the perils of doubly checked locking' from alexandescu (http://erdani.com/publications/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf)

Comment: Pity, [`std::call_once()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/once_flag), at expense of making instances of the class non-copyable, would have been useful (see https://ideone.com/lwwALg). There is also a `boost::call_once()` but ...

Comment: This is **impossible** without external libraries or C++11, as before C++11, threads only existed as external library constructs. Why the bizarre requirements?

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to **c++11** you can use `std::mutex` to lock prevent multiple threads from initializing the lazy section.  (Note: `std::mutex` only became available on Windows with VS2012)

You can even perform a scoped aquisition of the mutex with `std::lock_guard`:

```
private:

std::mutex m_init_mutex;

public:

Foo getMyFoo() const
{
    {
       std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_init_mutex);
       if (myFoo_m == NULL)
       {
          myFoo_m = new Foo();
          // perform initialization
       }
    }
```

**EDIT**: The OPs now stated that C++11 isn't an option, but perhaps this answer will be useful in the future

Comment: Or use "std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_init_mutex);" at the start of the block to make it exception safe and less likely you'll forget the unlock - edit: this is changed so this comment no longer makes sense but left it here so the replies work...

Comment: I would suggest removing the first version, as it is in no way preferable to the second one.

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately I do not have access to C++11.

Comment: @user93353: because it doesn't work in C++. Is not guaranteed to work, I should say.

Comment: @Mikeyg36 In that case you'll probably have to either use a library like boost which provides cross OS support or you'll need to write your own C++ wrappers for OS specific calls such as `EnterCriticalSection` (on windows).

Comment: so even if the code base I am using already has a platform independent mutex, I cannot rely on double check locking, correct?

Comment: @Mikeyg36 You certainly couldn't implemented double check locking in a portable way....

Answer (score 4):

By saying "no C++11", "no Boost or other third-party code", "must work on Windows and Linux", you have restricted yourself to using implementation-specific locking mechanisms.

I think your best option is to define a simple lock class for yourself, and implement it to use pthread_mutex on Linux and a CriticalSection on Windows. Possibly you already have some platform-specific code, to start the threads in the first place.

You could try something like Windows Services for UNIX to avoid writing platform-specific code, but it's probably not worth it for one lock. And although it's supplied by Microsoft, you'd probably consider it an external library anyway.

Comment: Hi Steve, I have a platform independent mutex class in my code base. But if I cannot do double check locking what do I do with it?

Comment: @Mikeyg36 You can use your mutex class in much the way way as in my answer.  Double check locking is an optimizing pattern which prevents you having to acquire the lock if initialization has already taken place.

Comment: This is the best answer here. If you've got such a strict set of limitations (which sounds totally absurd, by the way), this is the only way you can achieve what you need. It's also the hardest.

Comment: @Benj ah I see, I just looked at the Meyers article again. the issue only comes up with the double check, not a single check. thanks.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar I agree, it is absurd, but it is not my choice.

Answer (score 1):

**Warning:** I didn't see the "no C++11" requirement, so please disregard the answer.

Since C++11 mandates that static variable initialization be thread-safe, here's a simple way that you might consider "cheating":

```
Foo init_foo()
{
    // initialize and return a Foo
}

Foo & get_instance_lazily()
{
    static Foo impl = init_foo();
    return impl;
}
```

The instance will be initialized the first time that you call `get_instance_lazily()`, and thread-safely so.

Comment: The questioner doesn't have C++11, and IIRC MSVC doesn't do thread-safe static initialization in old versions (I'm not even sure it does it in C++11 yet).

Comment: @SteveJessop: GCC implements this correctly. But indeed, this is more of a "future" answer.

Comment: @KerrekSB Would this be safe if multiple instances of Foo existed which needed to be initialized?

Comment: @Benj: Well, the initialization of each static variable is safe. If you have multiple, separate static variables, those may be initialized concurrently, so you have to be careful if that's a problem.